# Django: Can not understand TIME_ZONE configuration

Tags: django, django-settings, django-timezone

I have tested some timezone configuration to better understand about how django timezone works.

But still cannot understand how it works.

Have some questions and need your helps

*Q1.*

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

1. TIME_ZONE='UTC', USE_TZ=True
    - datetime.now() => 2018-02-13 23:26:01.576493      // naive..
2. TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True
    - datetime.now() => 2018-02-13 23:26:01.576493    // tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Seoul' KST+9:00:00 STD>
```

=> Why in `'UTC'` case return `naive` datetime object...? As like in 2, I think it should return the `tzinfo=<UTC>` object...

*Q2.*

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

1. TIME_ZONE='Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ=True
    - timezone.now() => 2018-02-13 23:25:32.768780    // tzinfo=<UTC> object

2. TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ = False
    - timezone.now() => 2018-02-14 08:24:04.810045    // naive
```

=> why does `timezone.now()` returns `tzinfo=<UTC> object` in first case, even though I set the `TIME_ZONE` as `'Asia/Seoul'`?

*Q3.*

```
1. TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul', USE_TZ = False
    - timezone.localtime() => ValueError: localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

Why does it occur error even though I set a `TIME_ZONE`?

Additionally, cannot understand what exactly `USE_TZ` is (its role..etc) even after reading django official docs. I think that official documentation is like, easy to read only for the one who already knows what those are.. T_T

Answer (score 2):

Q1.

`datetime.now()` is a Python utility, it has nothing to do with Django and will not be affected by any Django settings. In fact, your second result is incorrect, `tzinfo` will be `None` in both cases.

Q2.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now): "If `USE_TZ` is `True`, this will be an aware datetime representing the current time in `UTC`". `TIME_ZONE` is not relevant here.

Q3.

As above, if `USE_TZ` is `False` the datetime is naive. And the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) says: "[localtime] doesn’t work on naive datetimes".

Comment: Thanks for correction and reply. One question more. If I use `PostgreSQL`, which support database timezone, shouldn't I set `TIME_ZONE` value like [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#time-zone) said?

Comment: @user3595632: That page says that it's an error to set the `DATABASES` `TIME_ZONE` if you're using PostgreSQL, since you don't need Django to convert timezones on the fly when the database already supports them. As mentioned in the [database documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#optimizing-postgresql-s-configuration) Django will make sure it's PostgreSQL connections are using UTC.